# Get the amount of elements higher than a particular one

Tags: php, arrays

I have this in my php code:

```
$aNumbers = array(2,8,9,5.5,4,5.5,6,7,8,9,10,1,'NB');
```

From this I must determine the amount of values above 5.5 and the average of all numbers combined. Using only a For Loop, if/else construction and the count() function.

I have tried to solve this myself, but nowhere on the internet I can find sufficient information.

Comment: _I have tried to solve this myself_ - Very good! Let see your effort!

Comment: Is this some sort of homework? Seems very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36470878/3933332

Comment: so, a whole class of students have an assignment, and they all ask here first for the solution? sigh

Comment: *the average of all numbers* Do you mean all numbers higher than 5.5 or literally all numbers from the array? Also to get all numbers from the array higher than 5.5 you can loop through the array with a simple for loop, check with an if statement if the value is higher than 5.5, if it is put it in a new array. Also for the average, just count all values together, you can do this in the same loop, and then just divide the number by the amount of element from the array, which would be `count($array)` .

Comment: Reported as... homework? Is that even against SO's rules?

Comment: @DavidWyly Homework questions per se are totally fine. As long as they are well asked and [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) they can be very good questions. Right now it would help to see what OP's current code looks like, so we can help him specifically and explain where he got stuck and how to solve the problem. Also as I read it, it is not totally clear if *"the average of all numbers"* refers to all numbers above 5.5 or all numbers from the array in general.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$aNumbers = array(2,8,9,5.5,4,5.5,6,7,8,9,10,1,'NB');

const HIGH_VALUE_CUTOFF = 5.5;

$uncleanArrayCount = count($aNumbers);
$cleanArray = array();
$highValueCount = 0;
$sum = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $uncleanArrayCount; $i++) {
    if ($aNumbers[$i] > 0) { // catch only numbers
        $sum += $aNumbers[$i];
        $cleanArray[] = $aNumbers[$i]; // builds an array of numbers
    }
    if ($aNumbers[$i] > HIGH_VALUE_CUTOFF) {
        $highValueCount++;
    }
}

$average = $sum / count($cleanArray);

echo "Average: $average <br />";
echo "Numbers above " . HIGH_VALUE_CUTOFF . ": $highValueCount";
```

Next time, post what you've tried. 'Twas fun doing your homework for you!

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

    $sum = 0;
    $amount = 0;
    $aNumbers = array(2, 8, 9, 5.5, 4, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 'NB');

    foreach ($aNumbers as $value){
        if($value > 5){
            $sum += $value;
            $amount++;
        }
    }

    echo "Sum : " . $sum . " -  Average : ". ($sum / $amount);

?>
```

Comment: I like it how your suggestion violates the "only for loop" rule - truly evil help, but effective to an extent. :)

Comment: @Sven too much Java for today.. ^^